# Why does the Julius speech recognition engine return a segmentation fault when passing a WAV file?

Tags: segmentation-fault, speech-recognition

I installed the `julius` and `julius-voxforge` packages on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and now I'm trying to run the `julius` command on a WAV file called test.wav. I ran this command:

```
julius -input raw test.wav
```

but it simply says "Segmentation fault" without any further information. I've been searching the documentation for a few hours now, and I can't find any relevant information.

Comment: Not of much help I'm afraid but I Googled `julius segmentation fault` and found [Voice Recognition in Ubuntu](http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2012/02/25/voice-recognition-in-ubuntu/) which mentions encountering a segmentation fault way down the page in the section titled "Running on YouTube Videos". Maybe you could contact the blogger?

Comment: Just try pocketsphinx, it works without a problem for me. Voxforge models for pocketsphinx are even more accurate. See for details http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Any more information? All I see in the repositories are libraries, e.g. for Python. Is there a terminal application built around this that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, there is pocketsphinx_continuous binary. To decode 16khz 16bit mono wav file use pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev The command you suggest returns an error of `Unknown argument name '-infile'`, and according to its man page, no such argument exists for the `pocketsphinx_continuous` binary, which is installed as part of the `pocketsphinx_utils` package. Any other ideas?

Comment: Make sure you installed the latest version - pocketsphinx-0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also able to confirm this behaviour in Ubuntu 12.04

Your best course of action would be to [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/julius/+filebug), so that you can get proper support from the developers.

Answer (score 0):

U cant give input directly on your CLI like this
Open terminal on the location where your Sample.jconf is present(Where your Acoustic Model and Grammer is present)
Then use this command

julius -input rawfile -C Sample.jconf

After that input your wav file with its location
Remember the input file should be in-
1) .wav format
2) bit resolution - 16 bit
3) sampling rate - 16000 hz
4) audio channel - mono

Answer (score -2):

I think that you forgot to call configuration file.
Like: -C config

Comment: Like this, for example? 
`julius -input raw test.wav -C julius.jconf`